# Write a SQL statement as a pivot table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server lets say you have a table like this called "Testing":

| Owner | State |
| --- | --- |
| John | Pending |
| John | Complete |
| Sue | Required |
| Sue | Required |
| Sue | Complete |
| Frank | Complete |

I want the pivot data to appear as follows:

| Owner | Required | Pending | Complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Sue | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| Frank | 0 | 0 | 1 |

How do you write the SQL statement to produce that? It seems the PIVOT table would come in handy but just not sure how to include that in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregates as Tim supplied (+1) offer a bit more flexibility and often have a performance bump

That said, here is a PIVOT option

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DtZ4y2kl)**

```
Select * 
 From  YourTable
 Pivot ( count([State]) for [State] in  ([Required],[Pending],[Complete]) ) pct
```

**Results**

[image]

**NOTE:**
If your table has more columns than presented, you would need a subquery to limit just the **essential columns.**

Here is a DYNAMIC version

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From ( Select [State] 
              ,[Owner] 
         From  YourTable ) src
 Pivot (count([State]) For [State] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName([State]) 
                                                    From YourTable A 
                                                    Order By 1 Desc 
                                                    For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p
Order By Owner'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: I tried to use a sub query after the IN  such as this: ..... IN (SELECT DISTINCT [State] FROM [Testing]) but it complained that there was an error at the SELECT statement of the sub query. Any clue how to do that?

Comment: @slashbrackets Nope  :)  SQL Server is declarative by design and does NOT support macro substitution.   That would require Dynamic SQL.   Many examples available

Comment: @slashbrackets Added a Dynamic Version.   Used the stuff/xml approach assuming string_agg() is not avialable.

Comment: The dynamic sql returned all the columns and all the rows just like a normal "Select * from YourTable"...even the same exact number of rows as if I just did that.

Comment: @slashbrackets As I mentioned in the NOTE:  If you actual table has more columns, you would need a subquery to "FEED" the pivot only the REQUIRED columns

Comment: @slashbrackets Updated my dynamic version

Comment: You rock! Works great! Just one minor question, where can I add an ORDER BY for [Owner]?

Comment: @slashbrackets See update.   Final line of the query.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    Owner,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Genre = 'Required' THEN 1 END) AS Required,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Genre = 'Pending'  THEN 1 END) AS Pending,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Genre = 'Complete' THEN 1 END) AS Complete
FROM Testing
GROUP BY Owner;
```

Comment: I changed the Genre field to "State" but that's not a huge deal. My next question though is what if new states are added. I don't want to have to hard code the values if possible.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL in this case.

Comment: Wish I could mark both as the answer. This works perfectly too if the values are known. Thank you for the lead :)

Comment: @slashbrackets You made the correct decision.